# arc radius ignored for decimal values

Tags: html5-canvas, 2d, transformation, scaling

I have some values that I need to plot into a 2D HTML5 `<canvas>`. All values are in the range  [-1, +1] so I decided to set a transformation (scale + displacement) on the canvas 2D-context before drawing:

```
var scale = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 2;
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

Each value is drawn using the `arc` method, but since I want a fixed arc-radius (no matter what scaling is used) I'm dividing the radius with the current scale value:

```
ctx.arc(value.X, value.Y, 2 / scale, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

Now, a `canvas` of size 200 x 200 will result in scale factor of 100, which in turn results in a arc-radius of 0.02. Unfortunately, it seems that values like 0.2 or 0.02 don't make any difference to the resulting arc-radius, only the stroke thickness is changing.

You can see this behavior in the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsjruquv/1/). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that after scaling by a huge factor your lines you now have a lineWidth far too big to be drawn correctly with stroke.
Just adjust the lineWidth to 1/scale before drawing, and all will work fine.

Comment: Thank you! Just figured it out 2 minutes ago